# daily, productiv coding in a Linux VM - a possible way to go?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, workflow, virtual-machine, atom-editor

I'm in a position were I need a lot commercial media software, so I have to use windows for many tasks. But for programming I really prefer Linux with it's shell and package manager.

If you could run a Linux distribution in a VM with a really fluent GUI, so that you could work productive with all your IDE in it, it would be a nice solution.

My experiments so far are not that good, is seems to be a bit sluggish compared to a native install (which is understandable due to the VM... but bad for productivity). I also tried the light distributions Lubuntu.

My mobile computer is a new i5 5200u (HD 5500) with 8 gb ram and a 512 SSD. I use VMware Player with it's tool set installed, which seems to outperform the virtualbox regarding GUI speed.

Is there anyone out there who works successfully and productive with his IDE (Atom, ItelliJ) in a VM Linux environment? OR is this a dead end? Any ideas or experience?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

Use as much as you can of the 8GB of RAM in your laptop for video memory in the virtual machine. In VirtualBox, VMware Workstation 9 and VMware Workstation 10 a maximum of 128MB of video memory can be assigned to the virtual machine. In VMware Workstation 11 2GB of video memory can be assigned to the virtual machine for additional workload processing power when running GUI applications. VMware Workstation 15 and later supports virtual graphics memory up to 3GB.

Use whatever IDEs you are accustomed to using in physical machines, and configure your VM and Linux guest OS with the objective of getting native operating system performance. Make the most of your VM's memory resources by installing a lightweight desktop environment in the Linux guest OS. MATE, Xfce and LXDE are popular lightweight desktop environments for Linux.

Comment: I thought this question might get closed for being opinion based, so now that it's on hold for being an opinion based question, I can legitimately add my own opinion. Since my answer has been judged as an opinion anyway, this is no worse than what I've already done, which is at worst I have expressed an opinion having the traction of an Apple watch and presented it as an objective fact. My opinion is "don't settle for a dead end solution". You can have the development VM you want with existing technology.

Comment: My 2c--you might find Sublime to be more responsive inside VMs.

Comment: Just want to report back: Your hint with the video memory inspired me to play around with the settings. It doesn't make a difference, but turning OFF the 3d acceleration seems to improve the GUI with LXDE. The only strange thing is that Atom does crash when using drag and drop now.

Comment: That's why it's called Atom, because of the Atom core application and all the wonky Atom extensions. Filip Dupanović suggests that you might have more luck with Sublime text editor.